# Getting data between certain time intervals

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Lets say an event happens at 11. I want to be able to show only if that event is between 1 hour before the event start up until event ends. Thanks for any help.

```
 from x in _context.Events
 join a in _context.Addresses on x.EventAddressID equals a.ID
 let aboutToStart = x.EventStartTime.AddHours(-1)
 let currentTime = DateTime.Now
 where x.EventStartTime >= aboutToStart && x.EventEndtime >= currentTime
```

Comment: So what's your question?  Does your query work?  If not, what does it do for some sample input and what should it return?  Does it not compile, or does it error out, or what?

Comment: How careful does this is query need to be? Do you have to consider Daylight savings time for example? You may need to convert to UTC before adding/subtracting times

Comment: Sorry I didnt provide that, but no it does not return the correct information. I think my where clause is off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create new `DateTime` objects on server with `.AddHours(-1)` call. Instead you should use [EntityFunctions.AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.addhours.aspx) method to calculate date time on server:

```
 var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
 var query = from x in _context.Events
             join a in _context.Addresses on x.EventAddressID equals a.ID
             let aboutToStart = EntityFunctions.AddHours(x.EventStartTime, -1)
             where x.EventStartTime >= aboutToStart && 
                   x.EventEndtime >= currentTime;
```

Comment: Never used this, can you provide an example also, would my clause get the results I need?

Comment: @user516883 sure, updated with example

Comment: @user516883 does this solved your issues?